# Vim invert block of text over an axis

Tags: vim

I was wondering what would be the most VIMish way to the following: I want to invert the text on the right side of the equal sign to the left (and the left to the right). For example, I want this

```
v1 = a1
v2 = a2
```

to become

```
a1 = v1
a2 = v2
```

Thanks

Comment: One sugestion @user191919, maybe this question should be asked on **[Vi an Vim Beta](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)** community.

Comment: Thanks for that, will post there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plugins that can do the swapping around an anchor:

- [swap](https://github.com/kurkale6ka/vim-swap) uses hard-coded (but extensible) or queried anchors
- [flipwords](https://github.com/mmahnic/vim-flipwords) provides a `:Flip` command that can swap (only) two words in a line, based on passed delimiter(s)

As Vim is about extensibility and has a very large and active plugin community (supported by the great backwards compatibility of Vimscript), I think installing and using a plugin is the most "Vimish way".

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands in Vim bellow:

**%s/v1 = a1/a1 = v1/g**

**%s/v2 = a2/a2 = v2/g**

Comment: I am looking for a general solution, I don't think this generalizes well... As I stated above, the specific case I used was just as an example for something more general.

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand well what you really wish your last comment wasn't clear for me.